# Correct clean up code

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

I have the following two routes for edit and new:

```
WZ.ExercisesNewRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: ->
    WZ.Exercise.createRecord()
  deactivate: ->
    @_super.apply this, arguments
    @get('currentModel.transaction').rollback()

WZ.ExercisesEditRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    WZ.Exercise.find(params.exercise_id)
  serialize: (params, options) ->
    exercise_id: params.get('id')
  deactivate: ->
    @_super.apply this, arguments
    tx = @get('currentModel.transaction')
    tx.rollback() if tx
```

I would like to know what the correct code should be in each deactivate so the store is in a correct state if the user does not save, does save or whatever.

Currently if I route to the edit route and then directly to the new route without saving, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `willSetProperty` on
>    while in state rootState.deleted.saved.
>   Called with {reference: [object Object], store: ,
>   name: name}

Comment: do you mean on exit of the route? Are you looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797338/ember-clear-form-after-submitting

Comment: The error happens specifically when directly transitioning from the edit route to the new route and then trying to change the model.

Comment: Hey, this is an old question, but have you figured out the canonical way to do this?

Comment: We have but you might not like the answer.  We stopped dealing with the ED model directly and instead work with a glorified hash until we are absolutely ready to persist, e.g. a user presses save.  Only then do we sync the hash with the ED model and proceed with saving the model.  This works great as you are not constantly running round or trying to track transactions.  It works but I wish there was a better way.

Comment: I call `deleteRecord` on all new instances of a record. For example:
https://github.com/collegedesis/collegedesis.com/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/routes/users/users_me_route.js.coffee#L17-L20

Comment: I do the same as @MehulKar. It works well enough.

Answer (score 1):

This question is for an older version of ember data, but answer would have been to first check the state for isDeleted and only rollback if the record is not already deleted.

In the newer ember data there is no concept of a transaction, but you can still run into a similar issue if you are trying to rollback a record that is not yet persisted.

I would probably do this in the routers willTransition event as you can do things like abort the transition if you want to give the user the option to save the changes.

```
  willTransition: function(transition) {
    controller = this.get('controller')
    if( controller.get('content.isDirty') ) {
     if( controller.get('content.isNew') && confirm('Closing this window will revert all unsaved changes.') ){
       controller.get('content').deleteRecord();
     } else {
       controller.get('content').rollback()
     }
    }
  }
```